# Was Ser Jorah Mormont's letter to Khaleesi a suicide letter?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Season 7, Episode 2 titled *Stormborn*, Ser Jorah Mormont is informed that his greyscale is untreatable and that he has six months of sanity left.  Archmaester Ebrose states that Ser Jorah  will be exiled to live out his remaining days with the stone men.  As a courtesy to Ser Jorah's knighthood, he will allow him one more day at the Citadel.

The next time we see Ser Jorah, he is writing the following [letter](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/game-of-thrones/news/a833977/game-of-thrones-ser-jorah-mormont-letter-khaleesi-daenerys-targaryen/) to Khaleesi:

> Khaleesi, I came to the Citadel in the last hope that the maesters
>   could treat me, as you ordered. Even with all their arts, I am beyond
>   any cure but the grave.
>
> I have had a longer life than I deserved, and I only wish I could've
>   lived to see the world you're going to build, standing by your side. I
>   have loved you since the moment I met you.

**Was Ser Jorah saying goodbye to Khaleesi because he was going to commit suicide or because he had failed in finding a cure and was going to live in exile?**

Comment: @steelershark: Functionally speaking, going into exile is the same as dying. You leave, never to return again. Therefore, it stands to reason that the same farewell message applies. You've rightly pointed at the ambiguity between suicide and exile; but that also inherently proves that it's impossible to make a distinction _as they are functionally equivalent_ (in regards to personal relationships). If we did not know what Ebrose told Jorah, we could also infer from the letter that he is going to die very soon from greyscale. All of these are possible, all of these require a farewell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it is never explicitly said, the intention is clearly present in the scene.

Earlier they discuss the advancement of his disease:

> The infection has spread too far. You should have cut off your arm the
>   moment you were touched.
>
> How long?
>
> It'll be years before it kills you. Could be 10. Could be 20.
>
> But how long until...?
>
> Your mind? Six months, maybe fewer.

The maester then clearly gives him the option to take his own life and even hints at it being the best option:

> Were you a commoner, I'd have you shipped to Valyria at once to live
>   out your life with the stone men. As an anointed knight, I'll allow
>   you one more day. How you choose to spend that time is up to you.

He says this while looking at the sword in the corner (obviously a ["Chekhov's gun"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun)). It is a clear hint that he expects Jorah to end his suffering by his own hand, a final honorable deed "as an anointed knight".

The maester then urges Samwell to leave him be, but Sam isn't done:

> Should we send word to your family, Ser...?
>
> Jorah. Jorah Mormont.
>
> Mormont?
>
> There's no need. I've been dead to them for years.

So he's got no family, and is struck with an incurable and very painful disease that will make him lose his mind in mere months.

No, Jorah isn't thinking about exile.

---

A later scene shows Samwell arriving with what he hopes is a cure of sorts, and he says:

> My name is Samwell Tarly, Sworn Brother of the Night's Watch, training to serve as maester at Castle Black. I knew your father. I was with him when he died. **You are not dying today, Ser Jorah.**

(h/t to Devdatta Tengshe for reminding me of this.)

Comment: Plus Sam clearly says: You will not die today Ser!

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Now, _that_ I didn't notice!  I didn't hear Sam say that!

Comment: Ser Jorah also glances at his sword while writing the letter, which shows that he's at least considering the option. (Without that, it could have just been the maester's expectation and Sam's interpretation of the situation.)